# Binning Variables in R by creating conditional statement

Tags: r

I currently have the field Time Departed. Time Departed is currently classified as `"POSIXct"` `"POSIXt"` . I would like to categorise it to `morning`, `afternoon`, `evening` or `night`.
My designed function is as follows:

```
mysizetwo <- function(x){
 if(x<0)
   return(0)
 if(0 <= x & x < 5)
   return(1)
 if(5<=x & x<12)
   return(2)
 if(12<=x & x<17)
   return(3)
 if(17<=x & x<24)
   return(4) 
 else
   return(NA)
}

dfFinal$TIME_ACTUAL_DEPART.bin <- sapply(dfFinal$TIME_ACTUAL_DEPART, mysizetwo)
```

Variable I want to base conditionals off of

[image]

Comment: What about `evening`?

Answer (score 0):

We can try with `findInterval`

```
library(chron)
c("morning", "afternoon", "evening", "night")[findInterval(chron(times =
       sub("\\S+\\s+", "", df1[,1])), 
           times(c("05:00:00", "12:00:00", "18:00:00", "22:00:00")))]
#[1] "morning"   "evening"   "morning"   "evening"   "afternoon" "night"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(TIME_ACTUAL_DEPART = c("1899-12-30 10:43:41",
          "1899-12-30 20:01:27", "1899-12-30 06:41:07",
          "1899-12-30 19:29:19", "1899-12-30 13:24:12",
           "1899-12-30 23:12:14"),
          stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```